# React : attempt to store data from GraphQl Query to state resolves in error

Tags: reactjs, state, react-apollo, apollo-client, graphql-js

I'm having a similar issue as this problem --> [How to store the data in React state after Querying it from GraphQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55327935/how-to-store-the-data-in-react-state-after-querying-it-from-graphql). Which covers the same issue that I'm trying to solve and that is how to store query data in state after receiving it instead of immediately rendering it.

I tried the answer that has been given for this question but I get this error:
`× Error: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate. React limits the number of nested updates to prevent infinite loops.`

I've been trying to resolve the issue of storing query data in state for A while now and have run into a wall I can't seem to get over.

With the answer given in the link above I've structured my code like this which resolved in the error mentioned above:

```
class ClientList extends Component {
    clientsToRender = [];
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
         clientFeed:[],

        };
      };

      getClientFeed(data){
          this.setState({
              clientFeed: data,
          })
      }
    render() {
        const CLIENT_FEED_QUERY = gql`
     {
        clientfeed {
          id
          firstname
          lastname
          email
     }
    }
   `
        return (
            <Query query={CLIENT_FEED_QUERY} onCompleted={this.getClientFeed()}>
                {({ loading, error, data }) => {
                    if (loading) return <div class="spinner-grow text-dark spinner-width m-5" role="status">
                        <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
                    </div>
                    if (error) return <div>There seems to be a server issue, try again later or contact helpdesk</div>

// ---- short term solution was to store it outside state which worked but is not what I needed
                    this.clientsToRender = data.clientfeed 

                    return (
                        <React.Fragment>
                            <div className="container">

                                <div className="row row-cols-3">

                                    {this.clientsToRender.map(client => <Client key={client.id} client={client} />)}

                                </div>
                            </div>

                                {console.log("state:", this.state.clientFeed)}

                        </React.Fragment>
                    )
                }}
            </Query>
        )
    }
}

export default ClientList
```

I've been stuck with this issue for too long. I'm really hoping someone can provide me the correct way to achieve this instead of mu short term solution to store it outside state.

Comment: You are passing the **result** of `getClientFeed` to the Query `onComplete` attribute, resulting that it will be executed at every render. You probably want to pass a _reference_ to the function. Try removing the parentheses. `onCompleted={this.getClientFeed}`

Comment: Hi, this indeed worked I can log `data ` in `getClientFeed` and see the correct data in logs but when I want to setState I now get this error => `×
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'state' of undefined` which confuses me ?

Comment: Ah yes, `getClientFeed` looses the binding to the `this` variable, so you need to explicitly bind it. One way is binding it in the constructor: `this.getClientFeed = this.getClientFeed.bind(this);` [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) explains some alternatives

Comment: I've managed to make it work by doing this --> `<Query query={CLIENT_FEED_QUERY} onCompleted={(e)=>this.getClientFeed(e)}>` but i'm going to try to do what you suggested because I think it looks cleaner

Comment: Tested it with `this.getClientFeed = this.getClientFeed.bind(this);` and works very well too thank you!